# If $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=w_0$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=|w_0|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

By assumption $|f(z)-w_0|<\epsilon$, whenever $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$. By consequence of the triangle inequality, $\bigl||f(z)|-|w_0|\bigr|\leq |f(z)-w_0|<\epsilon$ by assumption. So here will this same $\delta>0$ work?

Comment: Absolutely! Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that does work, by the triangle inequality you get both $$|f(z)|\le |f(z)-w_0|+|w_0|$$ and $$|w_0|\le |f(z)-w_0|+|f(z)|.$$ The first gives you $$|f(z)|-|w_0|\le |f(z)-w_0|$$ and the second gives you $$|w_0|-|f(z)|\le |f(z)-w_0|.$$ Thus, $|f(z)-w_0|$ is greater than $|f(z)|-|w_0|$ and $-(|f(z)|-|w_0|)=|w_0|-|f(z)|$ and so it is greater than their max, which is $||f(z)|-|w_0||$.

Another way to see this is to note that the map $z\mapsto |z|$ is continuous, so $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=|\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)|$.

Comment: @walcher..I was thinking that you have |f(z)-0|<$\epsilon$ when 0<|z-$z_0$|<$delta_1$ and |g(z)|$\leq$M when 0<|z-$z_0$|<$delta_2$ then you take $delta$=min{$delta_1$,$delta_2$}, now we can proceed with the algebra.

Comment: $|f(z)-0|\lt \varepsilon$ only if $w_0=0$. What is $g(z)$ and $M$? What do they have to do with your question?

Comment: sorry wrong response so sorry!!!